# Craft commerce 3 - Module - Lineitem - Get usergroup

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce, modules, plugin-craftcommerce3

I have the following code working. The only thing i have to do is to check which usergroup is the customer in. Is there a simple way to check what usergroup is the customer in? This is my first custom module.

```
Event::on(
LineItems::class,
LineItems::EVENT_POPULATE_LINE_ITEM,
function(LineItemEvent $event) {

    // @var LineItem $lineItem
    $lineItem = $event->lineItem;
    
    // @var bool $isNew
    $isNew = $event->isNew;
    
    $purchasable = $lineItem->getPurchasable();
    $variant = $purchasable->getProduct();

    // IF GUEST USER  > NORMAL PRICE
    $lineItem->salePrice = $lineItem->getSalePrice();
    $lineItem->price = $lineItem->getPrice();

    // IF USER IS IN DEALER USERGROUP > DEALER PRICE
    $lineItem->salePrice = $variant->dealerPrice;
    $lineItem->price = $variant->dealerPrice;
    
}
```

);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remembering a) that not all customers are users and b) that a user can be in one, or more, groups.....then something like this can be used to check if a user is in a particular group:

```php
            $order = $lineItem->getOrder();
            $user = Craft::$app->users->getUserByUsernameOrEmail($order->email);
            if ($user){
                foreach ($user->getGroups() as $group) {
                    if ($group->id == someParticularValue){
                        //do stuff
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks Jermey for helping me on the right track! This is exactly what i needed.